# Android CardView with rounded corners displays grey corners

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I'm inflating a custom layout with CardView inside the layout. 
The rounded corners are displayed as expected but I also get grey background behind the corners.

The code is simple, uses a CardView with corner radius and a background color. 
I've tried setting transparent background but doesn't work. However, if i set another opaque color, it is displayed in corners.

Code is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivIcon"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivIcon"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="@dimen/elementPaddingSmall"
                android:text="Initial Discussion"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/lightBrown"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_checkmark_circle" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please put this element inside your cardview  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: You can remove the `RelativeLayout` and have the `CardView` as parent and it would work. The `RelativeLayout` is wrapping the `CardView` and it seems that the border is grey whereas it's just the shadow

Comment: try to use  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" and  app:contentPadding="20dp" or some other value.

Comment: Simple work-around, might not be the prettiest but it'll work, is to change the `RelativeLayout`s background color to the same one of the container of the recycler view. The same shade of grey. If you don't want to waste any more time on this :D

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is because of shadow, you need to give space to cardview to show full shadow. Add `android:layout_margin="5dp"` to **CardView** and you will see that the "grey" color is cut shadow.

**Solution** is adding `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to CardView and it will give needed spacing.

Comment: `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` works. +1 for the shadow explanation! I wonder why this flag isn't enabled by default. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Other solutions didn't work for me

Comment: This is creating extra space around the card. How to avoid it ?

Comment: This worked for me, but it does add extra padding. To remove that, and the additional background color that you don't want, add the following (Kotlin) line to onCreateView():
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

Answer (score 12):

Try this...

Just set 0 value to **app:cardElevation**

```
.....
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
.....
```

**OR** you can call cardView.setCardElevation(0) to disable shadow programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parent `RelativeLayout` that is wrapping the `CardView` and you are good to go. Just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="@dimen/elementPaddingSmall"
            android:text="Initial Discussion"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/lightBrown"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_checkmark_circle"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: The issue was related to no spacing available for shadow as explained by Misha Akopov. What you suggested was already tried by me and doesn't work. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces the problem when the edges' color is **darker** than you set, it could happen if you set the color in `#AARRGGBB` format. To fix this issue, just set the color in the normal `#RRGGBB` format.

Answer (score -5):

Change `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` to `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.