# Cardview corner(edges) display with dark color,how to resolve this?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I use card view for display corner to my auto scroll view pager but cardview corner display with different color please some help me to resolve this issue

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp">
```

[image: See this image]

Comment: Attach a screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: Can you please add full layout code?

Comment: give margin to all side of card view or set card elevation to 0

Comment: @KrutikaChotara already added
   app:cardElevation="0dp"
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
Still not working

Comment: <CardView
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_5"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20">

Comment: try to use app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: @Shane sorry but, I try this one also. 
There is nothing changed on corner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android CardView with rounded corners displays grey corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261460/android-cardview-with-rounded-corners-displays-grey-corners)

Answer (score 11):

try attribute in cardview

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: You save my life!Thank you!

Comment: After adding `app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"` that leak is gone
I'm stuck on this from past 2 days!
Thanks

Comment: you saved my day! thanks. It seems to be related to the corner anti-alias issue, the background color somehow leaked a little...

Comment: `app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"`
This worked for me. Thanks @Ashish singh

Answer (score 2):

I set this param and it works for me

[image]

```
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to drawable file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey_light">  // here you can change color to white
            </solid>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dimen10"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and then use this as background for any layout

Comment: have you added tag i.e background in carview?

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/drawable_transperent_card_corner"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp">

Comment: simple background won't work on card view try aap:cardBackground

Comment: Refer to this link-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius

Comment: its app:cardBackgroundColor not app:cardBackground

Comment: Yes,there is nothing like cardBackground

Comment: Shivam can you send me a screenshot or code where this app:cardBackground defined.

Comment: Check this https://imgur.com/mZdoILf
CardView XML attributes list
CardView_cardBackgroundColor  
CardView_cardCornerRadius  
CardView_cardElevation  
CardView_cardMaxElevation  
CardView_cardPreventCornerOverlap  
CardView_cardUseCompatPadding  
CardView_contentPadding  
CardView_contentPaddingBottom  
CardView_contentPaddingLeft  
CardView_contentPaddingRight  
CardView_contentPaddingTop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but apply transparent background color to your inner views works.
If you have exoplayer view, apply it to shutter_background_color.